# Evaluating limit of sequence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I want to find the limit of

$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{a}^{b} (1+\frac{x}{n})^{n} e^{-x}dx  $$ where $ b > a >0$

Since, $\lim_{n \rightarrow 0} (1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}= e^{x}$, the sequence of functions do not converge uniformly so I cannot exchange the limit and the integral. If I could do that, then $e^{x}$ and $e^{-x}$ would cancel out and the final result would be $b-a$. I know that by using the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem I can show that the answer would still be $b-a$. But, is there any way to show that without using that theorem?

Comment: Is there any way to explain why "without using that theorem"? I mean, you know it, it does the trick, so what's the problem? BTW, you probably mean $n\to\infty$, the limit would be different, otherwise. And why do you think the sequence of functions does not converge uniformly?

Comment: @qwfwq The book I'm using puts off that theorem till a later chapter(which we haven't covered in our course so far), so I'm unable to use that theorem. My impression was that since the limit depends on $x$, so it cannot be uniform. For example, the limit for $x=1$ would be $e$ whereas the limit for $x=2$ would be $e^{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First a comment**

I don’t understand your argument *Since, $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}= e^{x}$, the sequence of functions do not converge uniformly*. For example, the constant sequence of maps $a_n(x)=e^x$ is obviously uniformly converging to the map $x \mapsto e^x$ on $\mathbb R$.

**About the question itself**

You can prove that for $0 \lt a \lt b$, $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ converges uniformly to $e^x$ on $[a,b]$. Hence you can switch the limit and the integral to conclude by using a classical Riemann integration theorem.

Comment: I see that my idea about the uniform convergence of that sequence was wrong. You missed a power of $n$ in your final expression for $(1+\frac{x}{n})$

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo!

Comment: Isn't $n\to0$ and not to $\infty$?

Comment: No it is $\infty$. There is a typo in the original question.

Comment: Okay. @balzacjohn7 Correct it.